# how to restrict access in routing.yml based on roles

Tags: routes, users

I know how I to restrict access in the routing.yml file based on permissions, but how can I do it based on roles? This is how to do it by permissions:

```
requirements:
  _permission: 'access administration pages'
```

How to do it based on roles?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work

```
requirements:
  _role: 'administrator'
```

See more details here https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes

Comment: It’s worth pointing out what else the docs say: _Note that, since the roles available may differ between sites, it's recommended to use permission based access restriction when possible._

Comment: @Clive thanks, and yes, I know it, the best practice is to use permissions. My answer is an additional option.

Comment: Absolutely, it's bound to be a good option for some people. Just thought it was worth mentioning the recommendation in the docs for people who have the option of using permissions and might not have been aware

Answer (score 3):

That *is* how you do it based on roles.

To complete the process, visit your site’s permissions administration and assign the relevant permission to the relevant role(s).

Comment: Since a role must have permissions, Clive is right.